# CLNDR.js - using 'eventsThisMonth' with 'lengthOfTime'

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I'm using CLDR.js with a `lengthOfTime` set to 6 month.

```
$('#someID').clndr({
    template: $('#calendar-template').html(),
    events: someJSON,
    lengthOfTime: {
        months: 6
    }
});
```

**PROBLEM:**
After setting `lengthOfTime` I cant use `eventsThisMonth` in my underscore-template anymore.

```
<% _.each(eventsThisMonth, function(event) { %>
    <h3><%= event.title %></h3> //nothing!!!
<% }); %>
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

[@tobiasriemen](https://twitter.com/tobiasriemen) Sure! Try accessing the variable `eventsThisInterval` in your template instead. That should do the trick.— Kyle Stetz (@kylestetz) [October 5, 2016](https://twitter.com/kylestetz/status/783709073275392000)